# How to list azure Databricks workspaces along with properties like workspaceId?

Tags: azure-databricks

My objective is to create a csv file that lists all azure databricks workspaces and in particular has the workspace id.

I have been able to retrieve all details as json using the CLI:

```
az rest -m get --header "Accept=application/json" -u 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces?api-version=2018-04-01' > workspaces.json
```

How can I retrieve the same information using azure resource graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to retrieve the information I needed by:

Searching for databricks resources in the Azure portal:

[image]

From there I could click Open Query to use the Azure Resource Graph Explorer and write a query to extract the information I need:

[image]

I ended up using the following query:

```
// Run query to see results.
where type == "microsoft.databricks/workspaces"
| project id,properties.workspaceId,name,tenantId,type,resourceGroup,location,subscriptionId,kind,tags
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to work with the workspace list api that returns json, here is one approach for post processing the data (in my case I ran this from a jupyter notebook):

```py
import json

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

# json from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/databricks/workspaces/list-by-subscription?tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0
# E.g.
# az rest -m get --header "Accept=application/json" -u 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces?api-version=2018-04-01' > workspaces.json

pdf = pd.read_json('./workspaces.json')

# flatten the nested json
pdf_flat = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(pdf.to_json(orient="records")))

# drop columns with name '*.type'
pdf_flat.drop(pdf_flat.columns[pdf_flat.columns.str.endswith('.type')], axis=1, inplace=True)

# drop rows without a workspaceId
pdf_flat = pdf_flat[ ~pdf_flat['value.properties.workspaceId'].isna() ]

# drop unwanted columns
pdf_flat.drop(columns=[
  'value.properties.parameters.enableFedRampCertification.value',
  'value.properties.parameters.enableNoPublicIp.value',
  'value.properties.parameters.natGatewayName.value',
  'value.properties.parameters.prepareEncryption.value',
  'value.properties.parameters.publicIpName.value',
  'value.properties.parameters.relayNamespaceName.value',
  'value.properties.parameters.requireInfrastructureEncryption.value',
  'value.properties.parameters.resourceTags.value.databricks-environment',
  'value.properties.parameters.storageAccountName.value',
  'value.properties.parameters.storageAccountSkuName.value',
  'value.properties.parameters.vnetAddressPrefix.value',
], inplace=True)

pdf_flat
```